# Validating json format

Tags: java, json, gson

I am making a call to an external webservice and they return response in json format as shown below. But when I try to parse with gson it throws an error. Also when I validate it against jsonlint.com it shows invalid json format. Now I wondering if I am doing something wrong or they are sending json data in wrong format. If its in correct format then what am I missing to parse it correctly

`({"data":[["0",22247,2764,99.96,0,0],["UNDEFINED",3,1,0.04,-2.08,0]],"totalCount": 2})`

Error `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3 path $`

Code `JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(data);`

Comment: This string is JSON valid (tested with http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

Comment: Is the brakets `(` and `)` are also in the returned string ?

Comment: @Maraboc yes the response includes ( and )

Comment: Then this the problem !! you must retreave them and your resulting string is a valid json :)

Comment: do you mean remove them. As you mentioned retreave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this :

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(data.substring(1, data.length()-1));
```

the result is :

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "0",
      22247,
      2764,
      99.96,
      0,
      0
    ],
    [
      "UNDEFINED",
      3,
      1,
      0.04,
      -2.08,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "totalCount": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These question can be similar like this [Gson Json parser Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906140/gson-json-parser-array-of-arrays)

You have to create an object like:

```
package pruebas;

import java.util.List;

public class ResponseObject {

private List<List<Object>> data; // parse the "data":[["0",22247,2764,99.96,0,0]
private int totalCount; // parse the "totalCount": 2
public List<List<Object>> getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(List<List<Object>> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public int getTotalCount() {
    return totalCount;
}
public void setTotalCount(int totalCount) {
    this.totalCount = totalCount;
}}
```

The you have to call the gson function in your code:

```
String json = "{\"data\":[[\"0\",22247,2764,99.96,0,0],[\"UNDEFINED\",3,1,0.04,-2.08,0]],\"totalCount\": 2}";
final Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseObject response = gson.fromJson(json, ResponseObject.class);
```

The data attribute have to be `List<List<Object>>` because you don't know what kind of object contains the json array.