# Convert JSON String to 2D array

Tags: java, json, string, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d Array like this:

```
"reels": [
    [
      "BL",
      "77",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "3B",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "77",
      "BL",
      "2B",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "LG",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "3B",
      "BL",
      "2B"
    ],
    [
      "BL",
      "77",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "3B",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "77",
      "BL",
      "2B",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "LG",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "3B",
      "BL",
      "2B"
    ],
    [
      "BL",
      "77",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "3B",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "77",
      "BL",
      "2B",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "LG",
      "BL",
      "1B",
      "BL",
      "3B",
      "BL",
      "2B"
    ]
  ]
```

I converted it into JSON string using:

```
gson.toJson(reels).toString();
```

The output now is:

[["BL","77","BL","1B","BL","3B","BL","1B","BL","77","BL","2B","BL","1B","BL","LG","BL","1B","BL","3B","BL","2B"],["BL","77","BL","1B","BL","3B","BL","1B","BL","77","BL","2B","BL","1B","BL","LG","BL","1B","BL","3B","BL","2B"],["BL","77","BL","1B","BL","3B","BL","1B","BL","77","BL","2B","BL","1B","BL","LG","BL","1B","BL","3B","BL","2B"]]

Now i want this String back to a multi dimensional array using JAVA only as it was in the first place. What can i do?

Comment: You've already used Gson's `toJson()` so why don't you look for the opposite operation and maybe some documentation on how to pass the correct type definition?

Comment: Sorry, could not find one. Thanks

Comment: Well, there is [`Gson.fromJson()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) for a start...

Comment: We need to mention a Class Type inside it

Comment: Well, that's where "look for some documentation on how to pass the correct type definition" comes in. At a first glance it looks like `Gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, String[][].class)` should work.

Comment: Could you please provide some feedback on whether my answer solves your issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

Define a class that reflects your data structure.

```
class Data {
    private List<String[]> reels;
}
```

Then use that in the call to `Gson.toJson`:

```
Data data = GSON.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
```

Related questions:

- [Gson Json parser Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906140/gson-json-parser-array-of-arrays)
- [Converting JSON data to Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"reels\":[[\"BL\",\"77\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"3B\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"77\",\"BL\",\"2B\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"LG\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"3B\",\"BL\",\"2B\"],[\"BL\",\"77\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"3B\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"77\",\"BL\",\"2B\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"LG\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"3B\",\"BL\",\"2B\"],[\"BL\",\"77\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"3B\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"77\",\"BL\",\"2B\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"LG\",\"BL\",\"1B\",\"BL\",\"3B\",\"BL\",\"2B\"]]}";
        Gson GSON = new Gson();
        Data data = GSON.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    
    class Data {
        private List<String[]> reels;
        public String toString() {
            String retval = "[";
            for (String[] str : reels) {
                retval +="[";
                for (String inStr : str) {
                    if (retval.charAt(retval.length()-1)!='[')
                        retval +=",";
                    retval +="\\\""+inStr+"\\\"";
                }
                retval +="]";
            }
            retval +="]";
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it by reading the JSON string as `JsonObject` and then reading `JsonObject`'s `reel` key as `JsonArray` into the target two dimensional array:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
// Read JSON string as JsonObject
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(reels, JsonObject.class);
// Read reels array key
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("reels");

// Iterate reels array and assign to result array
String[][] result = new String[3][22];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonArray reelJsonArr = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < reelJsonArr.size(); j++) {
        result[i][j] = reelJsonArr.get(j).getAsString();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do manual convertion of JsonArray to your String array, you should provide your own POJO with respect to JSON string as mentioned by @geocodezip in his answer.